# Incompatible pointer error when trying to get a HID device reference from HID manager on Mac

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, hid

I'm trying to write a User-Space Device driver to pull some data from a custom HID device. I'm do the following to store a reference of the device in the HID manage into a variable.

```
CFSetRef device = IOHIDManagerCopyDevices(HIDManager);
```

after this I do the following to register my callback which is setting up the report read from the device (another area I'm struggling with.)

```
IOHIDDeviceRegisterInputReportCallback(device, report, ReadDailyDataResonposeSize, Handle_IOHIDDeviceIOHIDReportCallback, NULL);
```

I'm getting an error in the above function on the reference to 'device' saying "Incompatible pointer types passing CFSetRef"

If I try to change the type that device is when creating it though I get another saying that it needs to be a CFSetRef. So I'm a little confused, anyone have any advice. I'm very new to  C as well as working on Macs. The documentation has come off pretty terse to me thus far.

EDIT: Here Is a link to the rest of my code for reference. 
http://pastebin.com/rFsHisdh

Comment: The information you've provided is incomplete for us to understand what is wrong. Please provide more details/code.

Comment: @ajay sorry, went ahead and included the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the signature of the `IOHIDDeviceRegisterInputReportCallback` function according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IOKit/Reference/IOHIDDevice_iokit_header_reference/Reference/reference.html):

```
CF_EXPORT void IOHIDDeviceRegisterInputReportCallback(
    IOHIDDeviceRef device,
    uint8_t *report,
    CFIndex reportLength,
    IOHIDReportCallback callback,
    void *context) AVAILABLE_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_5_AND_LATER;
```

As you can see the first argument should be a `IOHIDDeviceRef` and you are passing in a [`CFSetRef`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Reference/CFSetRef/Reference/reference.html) which `provide[s] support for the mathematical concept of a set` as **Martin R** answer indicates.

To get the elements of the set and pass the device (if any) you should do the following:

```
CFSetRef devices = IOHIDManagerCopyDevices(HIDManager);
CFIndex size = CFSetGetCount(devices);
if(size > 0) {
    CFTypeRef array[size]; // array of IOHIDDeviceRef
    CFSetGetValues(devices, array);
    IOHIDDeviceRegisterInputReportCallback((IOHIDDeviceRef)array[0], report, ReadDailyDataResonposeSize, Handle_IOHIDDeviceIOHIDReportCallback, NULL);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Do you happen to know of any other docs, blogposts, examples, etc... that demonstrate sending and receiving reports to a HID in order to read data off of it other than just the apple docs? Apple's do not seem to go into detail on sending and receiving reports from things that are not some sort of input device.

Comment: @Stavros_S Nope, sorry. The only thing I did find was the [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/download.php) open source library, which has some code to interact with the input devices through its [HIDInputManager](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/blob/master/src/SFML/Window/OSX/HIDInputManager.mm) class. Maybe you can get out some ideas from it.

Answer (score 1):

`IOHIDManagerCopyDevices()` returns a *set* of `IOHIDDeviceRef` elements.
You have to get one element from the set and pass that to 
`IOHIDDeviceRegisterInputReportCallback()`.

Comment: I see, Is this the case even if the HID manager matched to only one device since I use the product ID in my matching Dictionary?

Comment: @Stavros_S The function `IOHIDManagerCopyDevices` returns a set, even if it is a set with a single element.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem. You were pasting from an Apple document that is no longer correct ( https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2187/_index.html ). Your report variable is allocated in the wrong format, causing an memory error during runtime. Do the following:

````
uint8_t *report = (uint8_t *)malloc(reportSize);
IOHIDDeviceRegisterInputReportCallback(device, report, ReadDailyDataResonposeSize, Handle_IOHIDDeviceIOHIDReportCallback, NULL);```
````